# How do i get git commands (git checkout specifically) to run on the Odoo.sh webshell

Tags: git, odoo, odoo.sh

i want to rewind my odoo branch to the initial commit stage and have found this command for reverting it : `git checkout <SHA1>`.

Sadly when trying this on my odoo shell it said "fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git".

the SHA1 i gave it was the SHA1 of the initial commit of the main branch. I don't understand why this doesn't work. Any help is Appreciated thank you.

Comment: Are you in the correct folder?

Comment: @Oussama i think so, i navigated from the branch to the shell of the branch which should start in the correct folder. according to pwd i am in the /home/odoo folder if that is of any help?

Comment: Are you sure that this is actually a clone of the *repository*, and not simply an extract from one particular commit archive? Is there a `.git` directory in `/home/odoo`?

Comment: Unrelated to the above, I would note here that `git checkout <hash>` does not exactly *revert* (which in Git, means "back out the effect of a single commit"). It simply *extracts* the given commit. That's probably what you want, just beware of the word *revert* here.

Comment: @torek thank you i will remember that :)  and i checked and there is actually no .git directory in there so yeah that explains why it doesn't work. Thank you